# Should I use tickets "of", "for" or "to" a concert ?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> 1. I have two tickets for (to) a concert.
> 2. I have two tickets of a concert.

The first is a correct sentence, but the second is wrong.
Why can't we use the phrase "tickets of?"

Comment: "I have two tickets to a concert" is not correct, either. You can have two tickets to go to a concert, but not two tickets to a concert. You have this Beatles' song, "Ticket to ride", which can be confusing, but in that case, it's the verb "to ride", not a noun. If it were a noun, you should use "Ticket for a ride".

Comment: @JorgeUrreta - "two tickets to a concert" sounds perfectly natural and normal to this US English speaker.  [You can find plenty of examples of this kind of thing in live usage.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tickets+to+a%22)

Comment: @stangdon Seconded. There's no reason why "ticket to +verb" would preclude "ticket to +noun" as well, and I also hear the latter in just about every reference to tickets: to the fair, to the play, to [the Ex](https://theex.com/), etc.

Answer (score 4):

The preposition *to* can work as a shortcut for "which allows access into":

> That's the door to the other room.
>
> I know the codes to the application.
>
> I have two tickets to the concert.

*W for X* can be used to identify something W that leads to the main purpose or enablement of X.  If you buy tickets in order to have access to the concert, saying "these tickets are for the concert" is valid.

*W of X* means several things, none of which work with *ticket*  and *concert*.

- W of X can mean W belongs to X.  Concerts as events can't own things.
- W of X can mean W is from X.  Concerts as events don't usually generate tickets.
- W of X can mean W is part of or made of X.  Concerts as events aren't made up of tickets.
- W of X can mean action W was caused by X.  Concerts don't cause tickets.